# Read binary file with Deno

Tags: javascript, deno

Deno's doc doesn't seem to mention how I can do the following binary file read operation:

1. seek to position p from the beginning of a binary file;
2. read the next 4 bytes;
3. and turn what's read into a number (32bit integer);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use [`Deno.seek`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.seek)
2. Use `file.read`
3. Use [`DataView.getInt32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getInt32)

```
const file = await Deno.open('binary.file');
const p = 100; // your position
await Deno.seek(file.rid, p, Deno.SeekMode.Start);

const buf = new Uint8Array(4); // you can read more and then access a particular slice of the buffer
const bytesRead = await file.read(buf);
// ... do whatever operation you want with buf
```